# Upgraded to Gradle 3 and I cannot build a release because it doesn't seem to run my proguard rules

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard

I just recently upgraded to Gradle 3 and my Proguard rules were working perfectly before this version. I would like to know if there are any breaking changes made, I tried reading here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html but they only mention the basics. Any information would be appreciated otherwise I'll stick to 2.+ version of Gradle for now.

Comment: Upgrading Android Studio to 3.0 did mess up my project too. I'm sticking to 2.3 version for now.

Comment: My currently gradle version is 3.0.1 while my wrapper is 4.1

Comment: Hi josh, well I am currently finding ways to resolve this, it seems they messed up the proguard execution or were not aware of the changes they made to it. But damn if we stick to 2.3 the build time in 3.0 improved very much

Comment: Yeah 3.0 should be better. But right now I dont have the time to resolve this on my own. So I'm sticking to 2.3. But If someone come up with a solution, I'll go for it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that one of my older libraries imported was causing this trouble so I had to look for an alternative. Always keep yourself updated with the 3rd party tools that you are using.